# OleDbCommand not escaping properly

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm using bound parameters, but somehow this code won't escape the [ character. What's going on?

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Items LEFT JOIN [Categories] ON Items.[category]=[Categories].[ID] WHERE ";
query += " supplier LIKE @supplier";
using (OleDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    // create command with placeholders
    cmd.CommandText = query;


    // add named parameters
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
    {
        new OleDbParameter("@supplier", "%"+supplier+"%"),
    });

    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataSet dset = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(dset);

    return dset;
```

Passing a string with the [ character results in an error with the message shown below

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid pattern string

I have tried prepending [ with backslash but the error does not simply go away.

Comment: What kind of database?

Comment: It's an access database. *.mdb

Comment: Did you try with `supplier = "abc[[]";`?

Comment: @Steve Supprisingly, `abc[[]` works. How could we use this as a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this document](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/using-wildcard-characters-in-string-comparisons-HP001032284.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP001032250), the `[` and `]` characters when used with the LIKE operator denote a *charlist* like the ones used in regular expression.

This means that a single square bracket is not correctly interpreted and gives the error.
From the same document you can read

> You can use the special characters opening bracket ([ ), question mark
>   (?), number sign (#), and asterisk (*) to match themselves directly
>   only if enclosed in brackets.

So, if you need to search for a single square bracket you need to enclose it in opening and closing square brackets.

```
if(supplier.IndexOf('[') >= 0)
    supplier = supplier.Replace("[", "[[]");
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It indeed does seem to work.